# How to convert two lists to a dataframe without ['xxx'] tags in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created the following two lists in Python and want to convert these into a dataframe.

When I run the following code:

```
print(scores)
print('-'*100)
print(player)
print('-'*100)

dataframe = {'Score': scores, 'Player': player}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataframe)

print(df)
```

I get the following results:

```
[['1 : 0'], ['2 : 0'], ['3 : 0'], ['3 : 1'], ['4 : 1'], ['5 : 1'], ['6:1'], 
 ['6 : 2']]
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 -------------------------
 [['Tjeerd Westdijk'], ['Emiel Wendt'], ['Brayen Bröcker'], ['Kenneth Misa- 
   Danso'], ['Sabir Achefay'], ['Sabir Achefay'], ['Denzel James'], 
   ['Kenneth Misa-Danso']]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   ---------------------------

 Score                Player
0  [1 : 0]     [Tjeerd Westdijk]
1  [2 : 0]         [Emiel Wendt]
2  [3 : 0]      [Brayen Bröcker]
3  [3 : 1]  [Kenneth Misa-Danso]
4  [4 : 1]       [Sabir Achefay]
5  [5 : 1]       [Sabir Achefay]
6  [6 : 1]        [Denzel James]
7  [6 : 2]  [Kenneth Misa-Danso]
```

But I don't want to get my elements in [ ] . How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: post your actual `scores` and `player` contents

Comment: It looks to me that this has nothing to do with pandas, but that you have parsed a list of lists (of strings), so that the error is already in the `player` or `score` list.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I edited my question. Now it should give all results and actual contents

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix

```
df=df.apply(lambda x : x.str[0])
```

Fix from beginning

```
dataframe = {'Score': sum(scores,[]), 'Player': sum(player,[])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataframe)
```

Speed it up

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)))

dataframe = {'Score': itertools.chain.from_iterable(score)), 'Player': itertools.chain.from_iterable(player))}
```

Comment: `sum(scores,[])` is really slow ;) I'd go with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: Nice! ;) I think newer versions of pandas you don't need to `list()`, just the generator works just fine !

Comment: @Teunvdv yw :-) and if those answer do help , you can upvote and accept one of them

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension to convert the list of list to a single list , then call the dataframe constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame({k:np.concatenate(v) for k, v in dataframe.items()})
```

Or:

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame({k:itertools.chain.from_iterable(v) for k, v in dataframe.items()})
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is already *in* the `scores` and `player` lists. We can for example use a mapping to obtain the first element in the string:

```
from operator import itemgetter

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Score': list(map(itemgetter(0), scores)),
        'Player': list(map(itemgetter(0), player))
    }
)
```

Or we can post-process it in bulk with:

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].str[0]
df['Player'] = df['Player'].str[0]
```